# Relationships in multilanguage TYPO3 extensions

Tags: typo3, multilingual, extbase, typo3-extensions

Just assume you have the domain objects product and color. Each product can be assigned to different colors and each color is assigned to multiple products (m:n); the assignment is controlled in the back-end about the products.

[image: 1]

Next, suppose we have to translate every product and every color one on one. After all products and colors have been created it goes to the translation. First the colors and then the products are translated.

In case `A` I would assume now that if I'm translating a product, all the selected colors in the standard language would have to be replaced by the corresponding translations:

[image]

For a large number of products and colors that manual translation would be suicidal! Since for each language next to each product and each color also all relations would have to be recreated. But there is no need for that since the relationships remain the same in all languages.

In case `B` I would assume that its possible to keep the relations with the colors in the original language:

[image]

But on changes I have not only the product in the default language to change, but also all his translations. This is also not acceptable with a large number of data!

So for the case that the data must be maintained manually, an automatically synchronization of the relationships seems to be the only way to keep it manageable.

So my question is which of the identified variants `A` and `B` is the right to translate relationships? And is a synchronization via back-end hooks the only way to keep the cost of manually maintaining as low as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution seems not to translate such relationships like `colors` in the example. This can be achieved by using [`l10n_mode`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#l10n-mode) with the value `exclude` for the corresponding field in the TCA.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of using `l10n_mode=exclude` if you want to create a repository query that compares against this fields. This fields don't exist in translated records, so your query might fail. See http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2015/01/strange-code-in-extbase-persistance.html